# SSIS Packages stops without full data load

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am in the process of updating my SSIS packages to SQL server 2019 from 2014 and a few of them seem to be having a similar issue. For reference I have 12 tasks set up in the same SSIS package and about 3 of them are failing. They all use to work when pointing to the old server
When I try running in SSIS it will partial complete the load and then just say complete. No errors are being shown in SSIS even though not all rows have loaded.
[image: SSIS package].

I have it also set up in SQL server and connect to a job but when I run get the following error straight away.

[image: SQL Server error]

I have spent a few hours researching the issue but there doesn't seem to be much help online for it. Hoping someone might have come across a similar issue before.

Comment: you should be able to drill down further using the reports section. Alot of the times the actual error message is at a lower level

Comment: @Dougcoats When I drill down further in SQL server for reports it just gives me the same error. I thought it may be due to a memory issue but most other packages are working fine and some are much more complex and produce more results.

Comment: A couple of observations. 1) are you intentionally using an ODBC source paired with an OLEDB destination? Could be, but thought I'd ask. 2) Related - is there a query timeout that you're hitting with the source connection? 3) 65535 is a suspiciously round number (2**16 - 1). I don't know how that could be relevant, but it jumped out at me.

Comment: @tomfbsc have you gone to the table that ssis uses to sotre metadata? you might find more detaisl there

Comment: @BenThul  Yes i am intentional pairing the ODBC source with a OLEDB destination. I have this for most of my packages and they all used to work. Similar jobs within this package also have it and it does also work. On the timeout i believe you could be right with this. I always seem to  hit ~60k records and then stop. I checked my server connection and timeout is set to 0. I didnt see any option for timeout on my secondary Hana connection but will investigate into it

Comment: @DougCoats  I am unaware of the table which stores this. Is this a common table across all servers?

Comment: @tomfbsc https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2017/03/31/ssis-catalog-logging-tables/

Comment: @tomfbsc - Understood. I don't have experience with Hana so can't speak to it explicitly but make sure to check the timeout for the client connection (i.e. within SSIS) as well. If you have another package that's working, do a stare and compare.

Answer (score 0):

The above error was due to unicode characters such as ',' being in values field.
I got around it by removing them and it worked. Not sure entirety why this had to be done. Not sure if it was a setting which we should of also adjusted in SSIS as a staright upload to the tables in SQL worked without an issue. For text fields,  we removed any non- alphanumeric characters and converted the field in the warehouse to nvarchar.